# Swift: Can't create UIImageView from ViewController.swift

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, viewcontroller, viewdidload, uiscreen

I have set up my UIImageView using the below setup. I am trying to draw on the view but can not get anything to appear. I am new to Xcode and want my view to automatically change depending on what the screen size is. When I have used the storyboard I could not figure out how to get the view to change with the screen size and/or rotation. As a result I figured it would be easier to make that happen in the ViewController.swift file. When the program wasn't working I tried to see if the view was appearing on the screen. When I made one of the views red, I still could not see anything on the screen. I am very confused. I am open to any feedback. I appreciate you taking time to read this and am looking forward to assistance.

Thanks,

T

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ResultImageView = UIImageView ( frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var DrawingImageView = UIImageView ( frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    ResultImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    ResultImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()



    DrawingImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want a UIImageView to size to the screen.

Comment: Yes. I tried the code above and made a mistake somewhere along the line. When I did it in the storyboard I couldn't figure out how to make it change with the screen rotation.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: When I create the variable inside the viewdidload I am not able to see it throughout the program. When I pull the variable lines out I get an error that says "value of type 'NSObject' - > 'ViewController' has no member view." I appreciate the help.

Comment: Try now. I've updated my answer

Comment: The code ran but I was not able to see the red background for the image view. Should I update my post so that you can see all of the project view controller file?

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer so try it now and see if it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You are Awesome! It worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you have to create the imageview in viewDidAppear if you're setting the screen size, because the screen size hasn't been set and orientated where you're setting it. Try the below and hope this issue gets resolved soon :)

```
var ResultImageView = UIImageView()
var DrawingImageView = UIImageView()
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(true)
   ResultImageView = UIImageView (frame: self.view.frame)
   DrawingImageView = UIImageView (frame: self.view.frame)
   ResultImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
   self.view.addSubview(ResultImageView)
   self.view.addSubview(DrawingImageView)
   ResultImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()



   DrawingImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

}